# grub-install dummy fails. this is a fatal error

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, grub2

I am new to this but I have watched many video how to dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8.
I have HP pavilion g6 notebook with 4 GB RAM and Intel i5 processor.
I am installing Ubuntu 13.10 with windows 8.
In the process of installation I select something else then make some partion as mentioned here. 
/dev/sda6.   2048 mb of swap area
/dev/sda7.   18 GB of / 
And then I click on install.
When installation starts it stuck when grub is installing
And message arose as grub install dummy fails. This is a fatal error.
I have searched about this on Google many others have faced same problem but none of them helped me.
I think the problem is of uefi system.
Is there any way so I can dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Click on something else

And then don't create the swap space manually

Just create an ext4 partition and let the os decide the swap space for you.

But the problem u mentioned occurs when the grub menu can't read the os from the first priority partition. So, when don't you choose the option - Install ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: So, What you want me to do? when i try to install this option is not there that install ubuntu alongside windows

Comment: Did you try this? - askubuntu.com/questions/318271/grub-install-dummy-failed

Comment: You can try this tutorial as to how to install ubuntu in EFI mode - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of them but nothing helped.

Comment: Try installing ubuntu on Windows 8 following these instructions - askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: I still get the same problem. I followed each and every step but it still cause same error.

Comment: It can also help to put something bootable first on your partition table.